# How do I add hit highlighting to a Windows 8 search result app page?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

On the [Guidelines and checklist for search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx) MSDN the following recommendation is given:

**Indicate why a search result matches the query.**

For example, the Contoso app's search results page in the screen shot highlights the user's query ("item") in each result. This is called hit highlighting.

[image]

I was wondering how to implement this in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight Behavior from [winrt xaml toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) should do the job.